# ThreadPoolTaskExecutor throws RejectedExecutionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java.util.concurrent, completable-future

I want to implement following behaviour:

1. Read n events from file
2. Process them i n threads
3. Go back to to step 1 if any events remains

I wrote following app to test solution but it fails in random moment, eg.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
Caused by: org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException: Executor [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@62b3df3a[Running, pool size = 5, active threads = 4, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 70]] did not accept task: java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply@71ea1fda
```

What queue capacity should I set if I don't want to put events in queue? I want to process them immediately.

I am using Open JDK 11 and Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor eventExecutor;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean(name = "eventExecutor")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor eventExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        pool.setCorePoolSize(5);
        pool.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        pool.setQueueCapacity(0);
        pool.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(0);
        pool.initialize();
        return pool;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Start events processing");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> completableFutures = getEvents(5).stream()
                    .map(event -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> processEvent(event), eventExecutor))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            result += completableFutures.stream()
                    .mapToInt(CompletableFuture::join)
                    .sum();
        }

        long timeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        System.out.println("Took " + timeMillis + "ms, " + result);
    }

    private List<Event> getEvents(int n) {
        List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            events.add(new Event(i));
        }
        return events;
    }

    private int processEvent(Event event) {
        System.out.println("processing event " + event.id);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("processing event " + event.id + " finished");

        return 1;
    }

    private static class Event {

        private int id;

        private Event(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you either need more threads in pool to process every task by each thread without queuing or increase queue size so that task can be queued when threads are busy

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to change `pool.setQueueCapacity(0)` to use a positive value to allow for tasks to be queued up for processing when there are no threads available in the so-configured fixed-size pool (corePoolSize == maxPoolSize == 5).

The output "pool size = 5, active threads = 4" shows *approximate* number of [active threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getActiveCount--).

In theory it could happen that threads are not returned back into the pool before an attempt to process new batch of events.